# Multiple definitions in different translation units

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I know that for the one definition rule I can define a class in multiple translation units if they have the same tokens in the same order, but this program is weird to me

File **main.cpp**

```
#include "Source.h"

struct mystructure
{
    int field1;
    float field2;
};

int main()
{

    mystructure myvar;
    myvar.field2= 2.0f;

    myCustomFunction(myvar);

    return 0;
}
```

File **Source.h**

```
struct mystructure;

void myCustomFunction(mystructure& vv);
```

File **Source.cpp**

```
#include "Source.h"

struct mystructure
{
    char otherfield;
    int anotherone;
    bool anotheranotherone;
};

void myCustomFunction(mystructure& vv)
{
    vv.otherfield = 'A';
}
```

I'm using MSVC2012 and the compiler isn't complaining. Why is that? Is that normal?

Comment: O_O have you tried to add 2 methods with same name but with different "cout" to see what get printed on screen?

Comment: linking error, and I was expecting that. That's why I found weird two structures with the same declaration

Answer (score 3):

It's hard for the compiler to complain, since it never sees the conflicting declarations during the same compilation. But this code is not correct, unfortunately compilers don't pick up every mistake, nor does the standard require them to.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't complain because structure names are not actually exported as symbols from translation units. They are only used inside the compiler. Therefore you will not get a linker error even if you define two structures with the same name.

You will however get undefined behavior since the structures does not match.